# AmazonS3Client does not work in Lambda with FTP Client

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

The following code works fine in Lambda. That is until I add a reference in the project for a FTP client, such as CoreFTP or Fluent. Just referencing these projects causes the Lambda function to exit prematurely with no exception raised when it reaches the Wait() statement. Anyone idea why? I fear I will now need to rewrite this function in nodeJS.

This is only a problem when it runs in Lambda. The same code works fine elsewhere.

```
Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client();
var response = client.ListBucketsAsync();
response.Wait();
foreach (var bucket in response.Result.Buckets)
{
context.Logger.LogLine(bucket.BucketName);
}
```

Comment: It may be more helpful to show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: This is the code that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by downgrading the version of CoreFTP.  At the time of this writing I am using AWSSDK.S3 3.3.8.2 and CoreFTP 1.1.10